# How stacks work in mtg(can this scenario happen)

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers

A friend of mine and I are playing mtg when he tried to counter my Crystaline Sliver with Final Reward. Is this a legal move?

Comment: Are you talking about the video game version, or just playing with cards?  If cards, I would suggest asking this at [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).  Here, we only deal with video games, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Sliver is already on the board.

Final Reward needs to target a creature on the board.

Crystaline Sliver's shroud ability makes it that your Slivers can't be targeted.

So because you can't target Slivers, you can't remove it with Final Reward.

If you want to remove the Sliver, you would need something that doesn't target (like a [Wrath of God](http://www.magiccorporation.com/gathering-cartes-view-1912-wrath-of-god.html)) or something that would target the player and force him to sacrifice something (like [Diabolic Edict](http://www.magiccorporation.com/gathering-cartes-view-6641-edit-diabolique.html))

Comment: Thats what i thought as well. He played it as a counter and i didn't believe it was a legal move

Comment: Oh ... so the Sliver was still on the stack ?
Then it doesn't work because it's not a creature YET, but a creature spell.

This difference is important because many blue counterspells have clauses that makes them usable only in certain cases.

See :  [Essence Scatter](https://img.scryfall.com/cards/large/en/m19/54.jpg?1531451298) and [Negate](http://mtgbarato.com/images/cartas/El%20juramento%20de%20los%20Guardianes/NEGATE.full.jpg)